# Event dispatcher calling code function

Tags: c++, event-handling, unreal-engine4

I have a question about event dispatchers. I've created dispatcher in my code like this:

```
DECLARE_DYNAMIC_MULTICAST_DELEGATE_OneParam(FSoundPausedDelegate, bool, isSoundPaused);

UPROPERTY(BlueprintAssignable)
        FSoundPausedDelegate AudioPause;
```

This works perfectly fine in blueprints. However I don't really know, how can i make it to call function in code?

I guess it's going to be something with:

```
AudioPause.AddDynamic(this, &UAudioController::OnDelegateBroadcast);
```

What shall I bind it to? This is meant to broadcast value every time i pause/unpause my audio in blueprint and then execute more code logic depending on broadcasted value.

This is how my function looks like:

```
void UAudioController::OnDelegateBroadcast(bool SoundPaused)
{
    if (SoundPaused == true)
    {
        SoundPause = true;
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.f, FColor::Red, TEXT("True"));
    }
    else
    {
        SoundPause = false;
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.f, FColor::Red, TEXT("False"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is meant to broadcast value every time i pause/unpause my audio in blueprint and then execute more code logic depending on
>   broadcasted value.

So I assume you try to:

1. Inform other objects in game, that audio playback state is changed
2. Provide C++ and Blueprint implementation for playback change in your audio controller

My proposition is to create inner `UAudioController` implementation of playback change using [`BlueprintNativeEvent`](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Blueprints,_Empower_Your_Entire_Team_With_BlueprintNativeEvents). Base C++ implementation will use your dispatcher to propagate notification to other game objects.

This is class .h file in short.

```
    
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC_MULTICAST_DELEGATE_OneParam( FSoundPausedDelegate, bool, isSoundPaused );

    ...

    //Convenient Play/Pause function for blueprint
    UFUNCTION( BlueprintCallable, Category="Example" )
    void    Play();

    UFUNCTION( BlueprintCallable, Category="Example" )
    void    Pause();

    //Implementation for pause state change
    UFUNCTION( BlueprintNativeEvent, Category="Example" )
    void    OnSoundPaused( bool paused );
    void    OnSoundPaused_Implementation( bool paused );

    ...

    //event dispatcher
    UPROPERTY( VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintAssignable )
    FSoundPausedDelegate AudioPauseEvent;
```

Convenient functions simply call implementation:

```
void    UAudioController::Play()
{
    OnSoundPaused( false );
}


void    UAudioController::Pause()
{
    OnSoundPaused( true );
}
```

Implementation is defined first as C++ code, which also fire `AudioPauseEvent` with `Broadcast` function:

```
void    UAudioController::OnSoundPaused_Implementation( bool paused )
{
    if( paused == true )
    {
        SoundPause = true;
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage( -1, 5.f, FColor::Red, TEXT( "True" ) );
        // more logic...
    }
    else
    {
        SoundPause = false;
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage( -1, 5.f, FColor::Red, TEXT( "False" ) );
        // more logic...
    }

    AudioPauseEvent.Broadcast( SoundPause );
}
```

Implementation of `OnSoundPaused` could be then overridden in Bluepint derived from `UAudioController`:

[image]

Having `AudioPauseEvent` let you to notify other game objects. Example below show how to subscribe for pause change in level blueprint:

[image]

You could also subscribe other objects (for example `UAudioListener`) from C++ for this event:

```
void UAudioListener::StartListeningForAudioPause()
{
    // UAudioListener::OnAudioPause should be UFUNCTION
    AudioControllerPtr->AudioPauseEvent.AddDynamic( this, &UAudioListener::OnAudioPause );
}
```

Comment: That was really helpfull for me! Works like charm, good to see answer so deeply explained! Thank you very much :3

Comment: I'm trying to implement something similar, but can't find AddDynamic(). I only find Add()/AddUnique()/.__Internal_AddDynamic()/__Internal_AddUniqueDynamic(). Any ideas?
The code:
MySubsystem->OnCreateSessionCompleteEvent.__Internal_AddUniqueDynamic(this, FCSOnCreateSessionComplete::Cre &UCPP_AsyncOnlineSession::OnSuccess);

Answer (score 0):

You want another UPROPERTY called BlueprintImplementableEvent, this lets you define a code function that can be overridden by Blueprint. See https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/38960/blueprintimplementableevent-in-level-blueprint.html